# Find left limit $\lim\limits_{x \to{}0}{\frac{-\sin|x|}{x}}$

Tags: limits

I have a little confusion with signs. Thanks in advance.

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-}{\frac{-\sin|x|}{x}}$$
(This is a left limit, i.e. $x<0$)

Comment: What is $sen{}$?

Comment: @ChrisEagle It's $\sin$ in spanish (_seno_).

Comment: It's already edited, thanks for a while.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{x\to 0^-}$ when you say left limit?

Comment: that's that I mean Asaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x<0\Longrightarrow |x|=-x\Longrightarrow\frac{-\sin|x|}{x}=\frac{\sin x}{x}\xrightarrow [x\to 0^-]{}1$$

Comment: sorry for the dumb question but ...  $$sin(-x) = -sin(x)$$ is it correct?

Comment: Si, claro: el seno es una función impar....Yes, of course: sine is an odd function.

Comment: I see, thanks for the courtesy.